# OrbitControls.js and re-focusing orbit target on a new selected object

Tags: three.js

I am very bad at three.js - but I believe I have cobbled together a basic raycast on a set of objects, to select the object of interest.

http://designs.playgami.com/webgl_loader_fbx.html

I am now trying to have [OrbitControls.js](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls) focus the target vector on that object, i.e., once selected, be able to orbit around that object. I have tried a few variations, where some lead to what appears to be an empty (or out of camera range) scene.

`controls.target.set(obj.position)`

where `obj` is the raycast object and `controls` is the OrbitControl instance.

The quick(?) question: how do you set the orbit center of three.js OrbitControl given an object from a raycast?

Comment: For one thing, it should be `controls.target.copy( obj.position );`

Comment: @WestLangley just updated to .copy but it still doesn't seem to set the orbitcontrol target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the fbx model on raycast seemed to return one of its child objects in the child object's coordinate system (though the material coloring seemed to color the whole object). Setting it to the parent seems to have solved it.

1. Check to see if it's a child object or child segment that is returning the same local coordinate
2. for controls.target setting, the vector3 is an object that needs to be copied `.copy` (thanks @WestLangley)